# Lower bound on expected value of folded normal

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, absolute-value, upper-lower-bounds

For $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ the expected value of $|X|$ is calculated as

$$E|X| = \sigma \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} e ^{-\mu^2/2\sigma^2} + \mu\left(1 - 2\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)$$

I would like to see a proof that says for $\sigma$ fixed and $\mu \in (-\infty, \infty)$

$$\sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \leq E|X|$$

with respect to $\mu$. A citation would also be great to see! Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)